# Applying formula to a range using loop, error 1004

Tags: excel, vba

I am learning VBA and now I am trying to apply formula to a dynamic range of cells through a loop. But I get `error 1004`. I guess the problem lies in range definition, but I am not sure. Can somebody explain to me where's the problem?

```
    Dim i As Integer, j As Integer, k As Integer
    Dim lastrow As Long

    Set ws = Sheets(ActiveSheet.Name)

    lastrow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "a").End(xlUp).Row

    i = 37
    j = 8
    k = 0

    Do While i < 73
        With ws
            .Range(.Cells(i, j), .Cells(i, lastrow)).Formula = "=vlookup($a8,Ï!a:aj,k+1,false)"
            i = i + 1
            k=k+1
        End With
    Loop
```

The problem seems to be in this place.

```
with ws 
.range(.cells(i,j),.cells(i,lastrow))
```

Why is it not correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> "=vlookup($a8,Ï!a:aj,k+1,false)"

`k` is a variable. When you put it inside a string, it becomes a string.

Try this

```
"=vlookup($a8,Ï!a:aj," & k + 1 & ",false)"
```

Also you may want to make the LookUp Table constant?

```
"=vlookup($a8,Ï!$a:$aj," & k + 1 & ",false)"
```

BTW, `k` is a variable and you are not incrementing it. So why use it?

My recommendation would to first manually put the formula in that range and then figure out how you want to code it.

Comment: yeah sorry, i didn't mention that k is used for automatic change of column in vlookup function. I tried to put "& k+1 &"  as you mentioned , but macro still sends error 1004.

Comment: I tested the code before posting :) It works for me

Comment: Yes, it works :) but i switched rows and columns variables and afterwards it started to work. Don't know why

Answer (score 0):

H Bakai,

From what I can see within your code, I would recommend the following:

```
Option Explicit 'I always add this to force me declare all variables

Sub foo()

    Dim i As long, j As long, k As long 'I prefer long, Integer should be fine
    Dim lastrow As Long 
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook 'It is generally a good idea to declare the workbook before the worksheet so they can referenced correctly. 
   'Here I've set it to only work in the workbook where the code is placed.
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = wb.Sheets("Sheet1") 'Declare the worksheet. I prefer to use the name.

    lastrow = ws.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row 'again, my preference for this. Yours should work fine.

    i = 37 'Assuming this is the Col num?
    j = 8 'Row num?
    k = 0 'Increment?

    Do While i < 73
        With ws 'here you seem to have got the "Cells" part backwards. Should be "Cells(row, col)", but you've put it as "Cells(col, row)"? This might be part of the problem.
            .Range(.Cells(i, j), .Cells(i, lastrow)).Formula = "=vlookup($a8,Ï!a:aj," & k + 1 & ",false)" 'the Vlookup seems to be linking to another file here? "Ï!a:aj"?
            i = i + 1
            k = k + 1
        End With
    Loop

End Sub
```

Question? Is there a reason you didn't try this in a For Loop? I think it would work better than a Do While Loop?